# Does "that's" mean "whose" in this context?

Tags: grammar

"Insurance is another sector **that’s** European activity is highly concentrated in London and where Brexit may hurt. But the UK’s main competitors are in Asia (Singapore and Tokyo) and the US. The access that London has to EUropean money is based on proximity and historic relationships, not on being part of the EU. In short, even in insurance markets it is hard to see a rapid shift away from the City of London."

If yes, why can it be used that way?

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/this-is-why-london-wont-lose-its-crown-as-europes-financial-capital-2016-8

Comment: Ungrammatical.  Either "sector **whose** European activity is" or " ...sector, the European activity **of which** is ..."

Comment: To me, "Insurance is another sector **in which** European activity..." sounds better.

Comment: This is just a typographical error. The writer probably wrote _Insurance is another sector that’s highly concentrated,_ then began editing the article, added "European activity" and then didn't bother to finish his edit before submitting the article.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the usage is just a failure of proofreading by the author.

Comment: Hmmm. The author is Simeon Djankov. He's Bulgarian, and it's not unlikely that he is trying to apply the Saxon genitive to _that._ In that case, it _would_ be whose!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a mistake. The word "that's" is a contraction for either "that is" or "that has", which is clearly incorrect here.

Comment: Please explain why this is incorrect. Many of our users are learners and so they might not find it "clear". Also, _that's_ can also be a contraction for _that has_.

Comment: Anyone whose question was whether "that's" was correct in this context would understand that "Insurance is another sector that [is/has] European activity is highly concentrated..." is incorrect.